# local variable 'kruskal' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите решить проблему

----> 4     kruskal = kruskal(graph)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'kruskal' referenced before assignment

```
def kruskal(graph):
    kruskalGraph=[[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(N)]
    minimalSpanningTree = []
    marks = {}
    for mark in range(len(graph)):
        marks[mark] = mark
    while len(minimalSpanningTree) < len(graph) - 1:
        minEdge = getMinEdge(graph, marks)
        weight = getMinEdge2(graph, marks)
        minimalSpanningTree.append(minEdge)
        marks = changeMarks(marks, marks[minEdge[0]], marks[minEdge[1]])
        v1= minEdge[0]
        v2= minEdge[1]
        kruskalGraph[v1][v2]=weight
        kruskalGraph[v2][v1]=weight
return kruskalGraph

def union(graph):
    combine = [[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(N)]
    kruskal = kruskal(graph)
```

Comment: Это что? `kruskal = kruskal(graph)` С переменными в стране напряжёнка?

Comment: помоги себе сам, придумай разные имена переменным и функциям